# Scroll to top no funciona con AGM-MAP en ANGULAR

Tags: angular, google-maps

ya he probado de todo y no encuentro la solución, tengo una aplicación que cuando a través del cambio de ruta paso un componente donde tengo un mapa creado con agm-map, no hace scroll to top.

he probado esto:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { anchorScrolling: 'enabled' })],
```

también esto:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })],
```

Esas 2 líneas reemplazando por 'top' también.

en el ngOnInit tengo esto:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    });
  }
```

y también he probado esto en el app.component:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>
```

y en el ts:

```
onActivate(event) {
    window.scroll(0,0);
    //or document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Alguna idea mas?